# Device fails to boot when build with binutils 2.31 or higer

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot, binutils

I am trying to upgrade my current Buildroot build from 2019.11 to the newest 2020.02 release. With 2019.11 everything builds and produces a bootable image.
With the 2020.02 release everything still builds, but the device no longer boots and does not output any booting messages (no log data and no out via serial).

The Issue seems to be, the binutils version. In 2020.02 binutils 2.30 is no longer supported and the min version is 2.31.1 (this is the only legacy option in my config when upgrading).

Is this a known issue? are there any workarounds?

When I try building the 4.14 Kernel the build aborts during Kernel compilation. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513921/how-to-get-around-r-x86-64-plt32-error-when-bisecting-the-linux-kernel) encountered the same issues I had during the compilation of the 4.14 Kernel. So I guess a Kernel upgrade is not a solution.

Edit: The kernel version that does build but not boot is 4.4 .

Edit 2: The target hardware is a Dual-core Intel Atom (x86_64).

Comment: Did you preform clean build? (Like running `git clean -xdf; make ...`)

Comment: yes it was cleaned before the build

Comment: What makes you think the binutils version is the problem ? You also need to give more details about your setup: Buildroot configuration, hardware platform, etc.

Comment: The only difference in the 2019.11 and 2020.02 defconfig is the binutils version. Everything else stayed the same. That's why I think the binutils version is at fault. Furthermore, it seems there are issues with newer binutils versions (see link in post). Does the defconfig suffice or do you also need the kernel_defconfig file?